# Get an image file from canvas on metro app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm writing an app that let the users add elements (line, background image, textbox...) to a canvas. I then need to save the canvas as an image file. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using XAML in your app? There are already a few guys out there who have managed to save XAML as an image.

Does this blogposts help you finding an answer?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2008/09/18/wpf-xaml-saving-a-window-or-canvas-as-a-png-bitmap.aspx

http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/how-to-save-xaml-as-an-image/

Comment: Hi , thank you for the response.I'm using XAML,but (i thought i wrote it) i'm talking about windows-8 metro application and these blogposts don't help me.Thank you anyway

Comment: Why not? I thought you where trying to save the XAML as an image? That's exactly what's described in these blogposts. Are you expecting a full copy/paste solution?

Comment: RenderTargetBitmap,or WriteableBitmap.Render are not supported in windows 8 metro application

Comment: I think you are right, I did a few tries to build it myself but cannot find any of the methods needed to get a stream of the XAML or a method to render it. Hopefully they will update it with the release preview.

Comment: RenderTargetBitmap,or WriteableBitmap.Render are not supported in windows 8 metro application